# How long a fresh installation should take?

Tags: installation, nopcommerce

I have a remote database and a copy of nopcommerce running locally (from Visual Studio). During the first run I hit the install button and the page still appears to be loading some 40 minutes later.

I looked into the database and all the tables seem to be there. I didn't bother to copy sample data, so there shouldn't be that much stuff to be done beyond creating tables?

So the question is how long should the installation last? Maybe it is ok to assume that it's done and I can ignore the part where page still appears to be loading?

Comment: It'll not take more than a half minute!

Comment: Rebuild it and run it again..

Comment: @Div I looked into CPU usage during the install process and it could have taken some 5 minutes due to the database being on remote server. Likely the problem was with Newtonsoft.Json being referenced incorrectly. I had to reinstall it to get Nop to start. Looks like there were no problems with the installation (it only looked like there were).

Comment: OK, So your issue has been resolved?

Comment: I had to repeat the installation process for one reason or another and it hanged yet again. It looks like it took 5 mins again then started taking 100% of available CPU core and doing nothing. Probably should have went with local DB to avoid those issues altogether (except for the reference problem).

Comment: *except for the reference problem*, Yes I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption about "it's done and I can ignore the part where page still appears to be loading" is absolutely correct. Usually installation takes 1-4 minutes (depends on your hosting specifications).

But we also experienced this issue several times when the installation page hangs (but we know for sure that it's already completed).

Answer (score 0):

It can take 5 minutes or more to install NopCommerce on remote database when running Nop on local machine. It's probably better to do the installation on local DB (or put Nop on the same remote server as the database).

In my case Nop would hang after the installation was done, but likely it should not happen with a local DB (the hang is probably caused by the long installation time).